# Javascript API Share function giving error

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs

ARG! I am running into a problem trying to post to a users feed from a Tab application living on facebook.

I am using the FB.ui to post to the stream in this manner:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId  : '<?php echo FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID ?>',
          status : true, // check login status
          cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
          /*channelUrl  : 'http://www.yourdomain.com/channel.html', // Custom Channel URL*/
          oauth : true //enables OAuth 2.0
        });
      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());

function shareOnFacebook(){
FB.ui({
   method: 'feed',
   name: 'Example',
   link: 'http://example.com',
   picture: 'http://example.com/share.jpg',
   caption: '',
   description: '<?php echo urlencode($shareMessage); ?>'
 });
}
```

And I constantly recieve the message 
"An error has occurred, please try again."

When the user authorized the application - via the PHP SDK - I am asking for the 'publish_stream' permission... and have used this exact code in other application.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution for this? Any and all help is more than appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: make sure the appid is correctly printed, it does seem to me like an app issue

Answer (score 0):

for FB.ui you donot need any permissions because it is interactive, and use does at will, nothing to do with server side, do you have a test page we could look at

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      redirect_uri: 'YOUR URL HERE',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with people.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```